# includepdf not adapting to odd/even page margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, pdfpages

## An issue with centering

I am trying to include several pages of a pdf within a document (hence using `includepdf`). These take up most of the page, so a 1-to-1 page input to page output is desired. The main document is two sided with odd and even margins set and some fancy headers. When I include the pdf pages, these are not respecting the page margins (seemingly always centred). **How can I get the page margins to be preserved?** (I would also like the solution to have the included pdfs vertically centred in the space the text would otherwise fill). I don't want to enforce that the included pages start after a `\cleardoublepage`, but just a `\clearpage`.

## Undesired alignment from `includepdf`

Using the code (as in the MWE)

```
\includepdf[page={3-4}, frame, trim={30mm 50mm 30mm 50mm}, clip=true, pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}},width=\linewidth]{dummy_pages}
```

[image]

## The sort of alignment I want from `includegraphics`

Instead using:

```
\noindent
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, page=3, trim={30mm 60mm 30mm 60mm}, clip=true]{dummy_pages}}
```

The alignment here is better albeit I think the inner margin is still not perfectly aligned despite stating `width=\linewidth`.

[image]

## MWE

**I have created a pdf file called `dummy_pages.pdf` which is dozens of page of lipsum.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm, right=30mm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=24mm,  marginparsep=3mm, headsep=10mm]{geometry} 

% The nice headers and footers.
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Specifying the headers and footers. 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{1pt}%
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\clearpage

\includepdf[page={3-4}, frame, trim={30mm 50mm 30mm 50mm}, clip=true, pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}},width=\linewidth]{dummy_pages}

\end{document}
```

Here the fancy headers shows the page numbering and margins.

## Related material

There is a related question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91514/106804) to [how to position pdf with \includepdf in book, also depending on even/odd page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91250/how-to-position-pdf-with-includepdf-in-book-also-depending-on-even-odd-page). However, their "solution" is more of a one-off hack than a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this what `offset` is for? It adapts automatically to even/odd pages, so you just need half the difference between the inner and outer margins.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,calc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm, right=30mm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=24mm,  marginparsep=3mm, headsep=10mm]{geometry} 

% The nice headers and footers.
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Specifying the headers and footers. 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{1pt}%
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\cfoot{}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\clearpage

\includepdf[page={3-4}, frame, trim={30mm 50mm 30mm 50mm}, offset=-5mm 0, clip=true, pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}},width=\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{dummy}

\end{document}
```

[image: offset pages]

You can use the other offset value for vertical displacement, if you want that to be different.